# Need to validate textbox for a value

Tags: c#

I have a textbox which needs validation upon clicking my "Add" button.

The first check works fine when the other two checks aren't in the code.

The bottom two checks are fine if I enter a value into the textbox. However when I have all three checks, when there isn't a value, the program throws back an error saying

> "input string was not in correct format".

```
if (txtAge.Text == "")
{
    message += "<br>Please fill in your Age.</br>";
}
if (Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text) > 120)
{
    message += "<br>Age cannot be greater than 120</br>";
}
if (Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text) < 6)
{
    message += "<br>Age cannot be less than 6</br>";
}
```

Comment: why not use if-else this may resolve your problem as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are sure that input string is empty or valid number then you can use:

```
        if (txtAge.Text == "")
        {
            message += "<br>Please fill in your Age.</br>";
        }
        else{
            if (Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text) > 120)
            {
                message += "<br>Age cannot be greater than 120</br>";
            }
            if (Convert.ToInt32(txtAge.Text) < 6)
            {
                message += "<br>Age cannot be less than 6</br>";
            }
        }
```

otherwise you should also use [int.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) method to insure that string is valid number.

Answer (score 2):

An empty string cannot be converted in to an `Int32`. You should use [`int.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx) instead (so you don't even need to parse the value twice):

```
int age;
if (!int.TryParse(txtAge.Text, out age))
    message += "<br>Age is not a number!</br>";
else if (age > 120)
{
    message += "<br>Age cannot be greater than 120</br>";
}
else if (age < 6)
{
    message += "<br>Age cannot be less than 6</br>";
}
```

And use `else if` since if it's not a number at all, it does not make sense to check if it's in a specific range.